# Redirecting specific parameters to subfolders

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, url-rewriting

I've been searching around a bit, but unfortunately I'm still at a loss when it comes to this problem, and being far from a veteran with .htaccess, I've been unable to work out a solution to my problem.

The platform is Wordpress, but since I'm convinced that this issue can be resolved with .htaccess I don't think that that should make much of a difference.

I need to rewrite searches when they are made to a more friendly URL structure, unfortunately, just changing ?s=Test to /search/Test isn't going to cut it.  I need to pull 3 of the parameters out of the search and use them as subfolders, and then append the remaining parameters to the end of the search.  Here's an example:

Old url:

```
http://www.XXXXX.com/?s=Ford&z=59105&ci=Billings&st=MT&r=450&m=15000&pmin=1000&pmax=30000&status=Used&submit=Refine
```

New url:

```
http://www.XXXXX.com/search/Used/MT/Billings/?s=Ford&z=59105&r=450&m=15000&pmin=1000&pmax=30000&submit=Refine
```

As you can see, the parameters "status", "st" and "ci" respectively have been inserted into the url with all of the remaining parameters following behind.

So essentially, I need to redirect the old url to the new url, but have the new url display the page that corresponds to the old url.

I've got the following written so far: (**EDIT**:  *Changed {QUERY_STRING} to [L,QSA] as suggested by Explosion Pills*)

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/?search/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?s=([^/]+)?$ /index.php?s=$4&ci=$3&st=$2&status=$1 [L,QSA]
```

And it kind of works; you can type in the new url and it will display the page, though it seems that the "Used" directory isn't posting data correctly.  It's also only half of the puzzle, as it doesn't redirect the old URL to the new one.  It simple allows the new URL to exist.

Thank you very much for your help!  This one has had me stumped for several days. now.

Comment: Instead of using `%{QUERY_STRING}` as you have change `[L]` to `[L,QSA]`

Comment: Done!  Thanks for the tip, Explosion!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try this in one .htaccess file at root directory:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} s=([^&]+)&z=([^&]+)&r=([^&]+)&m=([^&]+)&pmin=([^&]+)&pmax=([^&]+)&submit=([^&]+) [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !index\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^search/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)   /index.php?s=%1&z=%2&ci=$3&st=$2&r=%3&m=%4&pmin=%5&pmax=%6&status=$1&submit=%7 [L,NC]
```

Maps silently:

```
http://www.XXXXX.com/search/Used/MT/Billings/?s=Ford&z=59105&r=450&m=15000&pmin=1000&pmax=30000&submit=Refine
```

to

```
http://www.XXXXX.com/index.php?s=Ford&z=59105&ci=Billings&st=MT&r=450&m=15000&pmin=1000&pmax=30000&status=Used&submit=Refine
```

For permanent redirection, replace [L,NC] with [R=301,L,NC]

Comment: That mapping works perfectly!  I notice though that when I enter the new URL it redirects to the original search though, instead of keeping the pretty URL.  Also, is there anything I can do to force all searches to redirect/conform to the new URL structure?

Comment: I modified my answer some minutes after posting it, please make sure you have the current version. The requested URL is always shown in the browser's bar. If you want the redirected URL to show, use permanent redirection as indicated in the answer. All strings are assumed to be dynamic, so any request with a similar URL structure should work.

Comment: Looks good, Faa; the mapping is working great now, and the URL is staying the way that it needs to.  You wouldn't happen to have advice on sending all of the traffic visiting of the old url structure to the new url structure would you?  I want to make sure that when using the website search, the new url structure is maintained throughout.

Comment: The problem is queries are different. If they were identical, there would be no problem, they are passed through untouched automatically to the substitution URL. In this case, it is necessary to assemble the new query with other parameters in the request and different keys order, so I guess that's the only way to do it and can't be a global rule for that task.

Comment: The way that my website is set up is that the user only has to enter their search query, other parameters are controlled by sliders and radio buttons.  As a result, I can set up a predictable key order.  Assuming that everything is in the same order every time, would a global rule be possible?  Sorry if I'm missing something, like I said, I'm pretty new to htaccess.  Thanks!

Comment: The wording in my last comment was not appropriate, what I meant is if the queries are different from the current ones, it would be necessary to adjust each rule. If their actual structure is the same, the code in my answer should do it as a global rule-set. As you can see, all query strings are dynamic so the only requirement is to keep the order and the name of the keys.

Comment: Well? If you are satisfied with my answer, you might consider [**accepting**](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask) it, selecting the check mark in the upper left of this answer.

Comment: Sorry about the lag, I'll accept it; I just wanted to see if there were any additional opinions regarding the second part of the question, first.  I think it'll end up being a redirect done within Wordpress; I'd wanted to post it to help any others in the future, but I'm still having problems with it.  Thanks again for the help!  Much appreciated!